# Пропадает Фрагмент внутри фрагмента

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view

Всем доброго времени! подскажите пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал
суть такова:
у меня есть BottomNavigationView из 4 фрагментов,
 внутри каждого фрагмента TabLayout с 2мя фрагментами
при запуске данные отображаются и при переключени Табов все норм, но когда я перехожу через BottomNavigationView то фрагменты внутри табов исчезают(именно исчезают) - подскажите как решить проблему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код
это основное активити:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme2)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_cash_box, R.id.navigation_statistics, R.id.navigation_receipt, R.id.navigation_reports))
//        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true)
    }
}
```

Это фрагмент с табами:

```
class CashBoxFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        retainInstance = true;
        cahsBoxViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CashBoxViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false)

        val image_calendar_cash_box: ImageView = root.findViewById(R.id.image_calendar_cash_box)
        val text_calendar_cash_box: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_calendar_cash_box)
        val spinner: Spinner = root.findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        metods(image_calendar_cash_box, text_calendar_cash_box, spinner)
        val sectionsPagerAdapter = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.let {
            CBSPAdapterTab(activity, it) }
        val viewPager: ViewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        val tabs: TabLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.tabs)
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        return root
    }
```

АдаптерТабов:

```
private val TAB_TITLES = arrayOf(
    R.string.tab_statistics,
    R.string.tab_revenue_by_the_hour
)
class CBSPAdapterTab(private val context: FragmentActivity?, fm: FragmentManager) :
    FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        var fragment: Fragment? = null
        val bundle1 = Bundle()
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                fragment = TabStatisticsFragment()
                fragment.setArguments(bundle1)
                return fragment
            }
            1 -> {
                fragment = TabRevenueByTheHourFragment()
                fragment.setArguments(bundle1)
                return fragment
            }
            else-> null!!
        }
    }
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return context?.resources?.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])
    }
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }
```

ПлейсХолдерФрагмент:

```
class CashPlaceholderFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var pageViewModel: CashPageViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CashPageViewModel::class.java).apply {
            setIndex(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1)
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false)
    }
    companion object {
        private const val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(sectionNumber: Int): CashPlaceholderFragment {
            return CashPlaceholderFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

и сами Активити, вставлю одну:

```
class TabRevenueByTheHourFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cb_rbth, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val labels = ArrayList<String>()
        labels.add("2017")
        labels.add("2016")
        labels.add("2015")
        labels.add("2014")
        labels.add("2013")
        labels.add("2012")
        val bargroup1: ArrayList<BarEntry> = ArrayList()
        bargroup1.add(BarEntry(8f, 0))
        bargroup1.add(BarEntry(2f, 1))
        bargroup1.add(BarEntry(5f, 2))
        bargroup1.add(BarEntry(20f, 3))
        bargroup1.add(BarEntry(15f, 4))
        bargroup1.add(BarEntry(19f, 5))

        val bardataset = BarDataSet(bargroup1, "Cells")

        val data = BarData(labels, bardataset)
        barchart.data = data
    }
```

xml основного активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_color_icon"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorBlue"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

xml табов:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/about_us_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_data_cash_box"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/statistics"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSilverB"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_data_cash_box"
                    android:entries="@array/array_date"/>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_calendar_cash_box"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_calendar_cash_box"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="@string/text_calendar"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_calendar_cash_box"/>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/raund_tab_backgroud">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorSilverB"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabMaxWidth="280dp"
                app:tabMinWidth="180dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorBlue"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/raund_tab_backgroud"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

xml внутри таба:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.reports.tab.fragments.TabLeftoversFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_rbth_clock"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_clock"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/total_rbth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:text="@string/rbth"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_rbth_clock"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            android:id="@+id/barchart"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_layout"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
```

ранее я уже делал подобное но Табы были лишь в одном фрагменте и все работало, я сравнил это с тем что работало и они идентичны, 
для всех я использую отдельные Компоненты, для основных фрагментов один xml, для фрагментов внутри таба отдельные
заранее приношу извинения если допустил ошибку, прошу помогите

Comment: Для фрагментов внутри другого фрагмента нужно юзать `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: @Circassian добрый день, большое огромное спасибо, работает))))